# Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported

Tags: opal

I have installed Opal Theme and i have this error:

```
Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` 
   in /home/mhd-01/www.triumphclubroma.it/htdocs/wp-content/themes/lexrider/inc/admin/screens/welcome.php on line 96
```

This is the line 96

```
<span class="<?php echo esc_attr( $status['time_limit'] ? 'pass' : ( $data['time_limit'] >= 60 ) ? 'warning' : 'fail' ); ?>"></span>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: According to the [tag info for Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opal/info): *OPAL is a high-level interface for low-level physics engines used in games, robotics simulations, and other 3D applications*.  It doesn't look like you are actually using that Opal. Might you please [edit] your question and [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it with the framework(s) and libraries you are using?  If there is no tag for your Opal, then please share a link to it or otherwise identify it in the text of your question.

Comment: Also, we will need to see a [mcve] that reproduces your exception, because as it is, there is not enough information to know how you got that error. See [ask].